# To align line of 3 units equispaced

Tags: amsmath, line-spacing

My tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x(\alpha) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}} x(t) & \text{ and } & x(\beta) = \lim_{x \to \beta^{-}} x(t) &.                        
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

I want to get the similar equispacing as here

[image]

**How can you do the equispaced line?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for `align` here as a single `equation` will do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x(\alpha) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}} x(t)
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  x(\beta) = \lim_{x \to \beta^{-}} x(t).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You may also be interested in this version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x(\alpha) = \lim_{\mathclap{x \to a^{+}}} x(t)
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  x(\beta) = \lim_{\mathclap{x \to \beta^{-}}} x(t).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The latter option is based on personal preference when there is a minor extension of the operator subscript. Too much and the `\mathclap` will make it look ugly.

Comment: I tend to separate with just `\quad` in this case leaving `\qquad` for the `\qquad \text{for all $x\geq 0$}` case (plus I create special versions of `\text` that include the `\quad` and `\qquad`